# Is it possible to have different color and font settings for comments when they start with # or ## in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, colors, comments, settings

I want to structure my code better with comments but I want to have different categories for comments, ones that describe the code below and ones that are more personalized for me and include what I want to think of later on, etc..

Is it possible to have different color and font settings for comments that start with `#` others that start with `##` for instance?

Comment: if they have different TextMate scopes you can use color customisation, if not you can use the extension `Highlight`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Highlight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) extension, put this into your settings.json:

```
  "highlight.regexes": {

    "(##\\s*)(.*)|(#\\s*)(.*)": {
      "filterLanguageRegex": "python",
      "regexFlags": "gm",
      "decorations": [
        {"color": "yellow"},
        {
          "color": "yellow",
          "backgroundColor": "#f005",
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "fontStyle": "italic"
        },
        {"color": "orange"},
        {
          "color": "orange"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

There is a lot of styling you can do with this extension, see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions

[image: python comment highlighting demo]